# The strange positioning of the adverb "overland"

Tags: adverb-position

What is so peculiar about the adverb *overland?*

> - The marine brigade in Belgium cautiously advances to Picardy.
> - The marine brigade in Belgium therefore advances to Picardy.
> - The marine brigade in Belgium overland advances to Picardy.

So, if your native language is English as mine is, you immediately notice that the last of the three is wrong; but why, logically?

Why should the following be so strongly preferred?

> - The marine brigade in Belgium advances overland to Picardy.

This is not a necessary question. Obviously, I already know how to write the sentence. It is however a curious question. Can you think of a good reason to answer it?

The best reason with which I can come up is that "over land" (as two words) is a prepositional phrase, but that reason doesn't seem to wash, as far as I know. "Overland" is a word, not a phrase.

Comment: I think that your 'best reason' is correct: *overland* is simply a condensed prepositional phrase. Consider similar adverbs: *I swam underwater,* but not **I underwater swam; I traveled overseas,* but not **I overseas traveled*.

Comment: Overland seems to resist being paired with other adverbs. ... advances swiftly and overland  ... doesn't work, and it should do.

Comment: @Anonym: Please feel free to make your comment an *answer* so that it can be upvoted and (apparently, since it seems to be the only answer) *accepted.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'best reason' is correct; although it is written as a single word, *overland* is simply a condensed prepositional phrase, and as such follows many of the same rules as a regular prepositional phrase would, including those about positioning.

So, we would say *they advanced overland,* not *they overland advanced* for the same reason that we would say *I ran up the hill,* not *I up the hill ran*.

Similar adverbs include *overseas, underwater, underground, uphill, downhill,* etc.